# Is it feasible to create virtual machines in KubeVirt through Python Client?

Tags: python, kubernetes, virtual-machine

KubeVirt is an extension of Kubernetes, enabling it to manage virtual machines.I have deployed a KubeVirt cluster. I want to use Python Client to operate KubeVirt to manage virtual machines. Is this feasible?

I use Kubernetes Python Client.But it does not seem to support the resource type of virtual machine.My cluster can create virtual machines through **kubectl apply - f testvm.yaml**

Python code:

```
from kubernetes import client, config, utils

config.load_kube_config('config')


k8s_client = client.ApiClient()

file = 'yamlfile\\testvm.yaml'
utils.create_from_yaml(k8s_client, file, verbose=True)
```

error:
`AttributeError: module 'kubernetes.client' has no attribute 'KubevirtIoV1Api'`

testvm.yaml:

```
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
kind: VirtualMachine
metadata:
  name: testvm
spec:
  running: false
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubevirt.io/size: small
        kubevirt.io/domain: testvm
    spec:
      domain:
        devices:
          disks:
            - name: containerdisk
              disk:
                bus: virtio
            - name: cloudinitdisk
              disk:
                bus: virtio
          interfaces:
          - name: default
            masquerade: {}
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 64M
      networks:
      - name: default
        pod: {}
      volumes:
        - name: containerdisk
          containerDisk:
            image: quay.io/kubevirt/cirros-container-disk-demo
        - name: cloudinitdisk
          cloudInitNoCloud:
            userDataBase64: SGkuXG4=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vm-ssh
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 24
    targetPort: 22
    name: test
  selector:
    kubevirt.io/domain: testvm
    kubevirt.io/size: small
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create resources that use the `kubevirt.io/v1` api. This isn't a core Kubernetes API; it's provided by the kubevirt [custom resource definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/), which means it's not supported by any of the static parts of the Python kubernetes client.

But don't worry, that's what the [DynamicClient](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/851dc2a0b10d1bc07826c6ade489d1bd2ef431c3/kubernetes/base/dynamic/client.py#L72) is for! You can find some examples of working with the dynamic client [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/examples/dynamic-client).

Your code would end up looking something like:

```py
import yaml
from kubernetes import config, dynamic
from kubernetes.client import api_client


# Creating a dynamic client
client = dynamic.DynamicClient(
    api_client.ApiClient(configuration=config.load_kube_config())
)

# fetching the configmap api
api = client.resources.get(api_version="kubevirt.io/v1", kind="VirtualMachine")
path = 'testvm.yaml'
with open(path) as fd:
  resource = yaml.safe_load(fd)

api.create(body=resource)
```